# Remove last line from CSV

Tags: csv, vbscript, scripting

I need to figure out how to remove the last line from the .csv file.  It is basically just a row of empty spaces but it is messing up the import process.  I use the following script to do 2 things (1) convert the .xls file to .csv and then (2) remove the last line from the .csv file.  The first part works fine but the second part isn't removing the last line from the file.  What am I doing wrong where it won't delete the last line?

```
Const ForReading = 1
Const ForWriting = 2
Set ExcelObj = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
ExcelObj.DisplayAlerts = False
ExcelObj.Visible  = false
ExcelObj.Workbooks.Open "C:\convert\ovations.xls"
ExcelObj.Workbooks(1).SaveAs "C:\convert\edited\TEST.csv", 6
ExcelObj.Workbooks.Close
ExcelObj.Quit

Set objFSo = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("C:\convert\edited\TEST.csv", ForReading)
strContents = objFile.ReadAll

objFile.Close

arrLines = Split(strContents, vbCrLf)

Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("C:\convert\edited\TEST.csv", ForWriting)

For i = 0 to UBound(arrLines) - 1
    objFile.WriteLine arrLines(i)
Next

objFile.Close
```

Comment: Use an If statement to check for the value you are trying to filter out.

Comment: Is it possible that the lines in the CSV aren't terminated with `vbCrLf` or may be the last line is also terminated with `vbCrLf`? Try `UBound(arrLines) - 2` or increment `i` if you encounter `Len(arrLines(i) & "") < 1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When there is a CRLF sequence at the very end of the CSV file (which is the case) then `Split()` will generate a part that *follows* that CRLF, i.e. an empty string.

The loop you then have, omits that extra blank string, but still keeps what came before that CRLF, and `WriteLine` itself also produces the final CRLF, so you end up with exactly the same result.

If you really want to omit the last line, you'll have to produce *two* fewer lines from the `Split` result instead of *one* less:

```
For i = 0 to UBound(arrLines) - 2
```

Comment: Corrected the answer.

Comment: Is that after [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47084009/vbscript-remove-last-line-from-csv#comment81118141_47084009)?

Comment: I just read your comment now. The last line is certainly terminated by `CrLf`: this is how Excel writes CSV. NB: Did you read the suggestion text that appears in a question's comment box before you start typing? ;-)

Comment: It was a suggestion not an answer.

Comment: That worked! Thanks!  I did have to change it to -3 though.

Comment: You're welcome... it all depends on how many lines there are too many in the original CSV (including empty lines). If this varies, then it is probably safer to just exclude empty lines with an `if` condition within the loop, possibly with a `Trim()` applied as well.

Answer (score 1):

As [@trincot](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5459839/trincot) points out in their [revised answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/47084244/revisions), you can adjust the line

```
For i = 0 To UBound(arrLines) - 1
```

to

```
For i = 0 To UBound(arrLines) - 2
```

and the code will likely work, as before the last carriage-return linefeed was not being taken into consideration.

---

It is worth pointing out though that this is easily solvable by debugging the problem.

- If a loop doesn't behave as you expect, check the data you are providing.

  Use `WScript.Echo` or `MsgBox()` to output the count of lines in the array `arrLines` then compare with the source file, if they don't match you know there is an extra line.

With some simple debugging you could have worked this out in minutes.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to avoid the For loop (for large files)

---

```
Option Explicit

Const ForReading = 1
Const ForWriting = 2
Const txt = "C:\convert\ovations.xls"
Const csv = "C:\convert\edited\TEST.csv"

Dim xl, fso, fsoFile, fileTxt, lastCR, i

Set xl = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    xl.DisplayAlerts = False
    xl.Visible  = False
    xl.Workbooks.Open txt
    xl.Workbooks(1).SaveAs csv, 6
    xl.Workbooks.Close
    xl.Quit

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set fsoFile = fso.OpenTextFile(csv, ForReading)
    fileTxt = fsoFile.ReadAll
    fsoFile.Close
Set fsoFile = fso.OpenTextFile(csv, ForWriting)
    fsoFile.Write Left(fileTxt, InStrRev(fileTxt, vbCrLf, Len(fileTxt) - 1))
    fsoFile.Close
```

---

Last line can also be removed in Excel (before the `xl.Workbooks(1).SaveAs csv, 6` line)

```
With xl.Workbooks(1).Worksheets(1)
    .Rows(.UsedRange.Rows.Count).Delete
End With
```